# Promoted links don't work in a page

Tags: web-part, 2013, promoted-links

I've set up a few promoted links lists and I want to embed them in a page as web parts. They show up just fine when doing this, but the links themselves are unresponsive when trying to use them through that page. The description scrolls up as normal on hover, but when you click them nothing happens. If I edit the page, the links work, but as soon as I **publish** it they stop.

Has anyone else seen this behavior before?

Edit: If I examine the link properties (of the non-functioning links) they simply point to the page where the web part is embedded. If the page has yet to be published, they point to the correct location. Is this a publishing site bug?

Comment: Most probably it looks like javascript error. But still kindly can you post your codes so we can help you

Comment: There actually is no code, it was all created using OOB browser-based customization.